# Wave animation for imageview android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I am trying to create a button with wave animation.
I do not want to change the size of the image, but to do effect of waves from the picture and outside.

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="1.3"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="1.3"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

But this changes the size of the image instead of sending a wave from it.

I want something like this:

[image: wave animation example image]

Comment: take another view and apply animation to that view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create this effect you will need to use `AnimationSet`, And add to it two animations, one animation would be resizing animation, basically changing the size of the view, the other animation would be a fading animation basically changing the alpha level of this view.

obviously they would be applied to another view and not the icon view.

Code sample:

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
 
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(sizingAnimation);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);
```

**EDITED (15/09/2020):**

Resizing Animation:

```
 private Animation getResizeAnimation(Context aContext, boolean enlarge) {
    Animation resizeAnimation;
    if (enlarge) {
        resizeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(aContext, R.anim.scale_up_card);
    } else {
        resizeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(aContext, R.anim.scale_down_card);
    }
    resizeAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    return resizeAnimation;
}
```

Where `scale_up_card` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:toXScale="1.03"
       android:toYScale="1.03"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="10%"
       android:duration="100">
</scale>
</set>
```

And `scale_down_card`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale android:fromXScale="1.03"
       android:fromYScale="1.03"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="10%"
       android:duration="100">
</scale>
</set>
```

Obviously, for you case maybe the needed animations are different.

Comment: what is sizingAnimation ?

Comment: What exactly is the sizingAnimation??

Comment: @KingofMasses sizing animation added to answer.

Comment: @VishistVarugeese sizing animation added to answer.