# How to set wave animation to the wave image in android

Tags: android, animation, wave

I want to set wave animation to the imageview.I used this animation it is moving the image to the right side but i want wave animation to the image.Please anyone help me to resolve this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="75%p"
    android:duration="100" />
</set>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wave animation for imageview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127154/wave-animation-for-imageview-android)

Comment: no i want to wave my image